# Why is it that some gates cost to start at a lower tier and some don't?

Tags: spiral-knights

I've noticed that some gates charge you 200 crowns to start on tier 2, and 500 crowns to start on tier 3, and that some gates don't charge you to start on tier 3 at all (I think there are some that don't charge to start on tier 2, but I'm not certain).

Why is this?  What determines whether a gate will charge you for starting low?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may or may not know, the gates in spiral knights cycle every 8 days, moving right to left. Every other day the leftmost gate vanishes, the leftmost mineral deposit gate becomes locked and becomes the rightmost gate, and a new gate spawns on the far right.

Every time a new gate enters "circulation", your Knight is "unattuned", and must pay a crown tax to jump to tiers 2 or 3.

The tax is removed when you take the elevator down from floor 7 or 17 to Moorcraft Manor or Emberlight respectively, and will stay removed for the lifetime of that gate.